# Mis marcadores no se muestran correctamente en mi mapa de google maps

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación .net con MVC y tengo un mapa donde se cargan unos marcadores de diferentes iconos, estos son traídos desde una base de datos en SQL server, en si mi aplicación funciona el problema que tengo que recargar la página varias veces para que estos se muestren, hay veces que los puntos se muestran a la primera, pero hay veces que hay que recargarla más de una vez.

Esta función crea y carga el mapa con una simbología

```
function initMap() {
    var h = { lat: 20.967778, lng: -89.621667 };
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: h,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    //var marker, i;
    //var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var icons = {
        i1: {
            name: 'BACHES',
            icon: '../puntosimg/42.png'

        },
        i2: {
            name: 'MALTRATO ANIMAL',
            icon: "../puntosimg/52.png"

        },
        i3: {
            name: 'LOTES BALDÍOS',
            icon: "../puntosimg/62.png"
        },
        i4: {
            name: 'VANDALISMO ',
            icon: "../puntosimg/72.png"
        },
        i5: {
            name: 'ROBO',
            icon: "../puntosimg/82.png"
        },
        i6: {
            name: 'INCENDIOS',
            icon: "../puntosimg/92.png"
        },
        i7: {
            name: 'ACCIDENTES AUTOMOVILÍSTICOS',
            icon: "../puntosimg/102.png"
        },
        i8: {
            name: 'OTROS',
            icon: "../puntosimg/112.png"
        }

    };
    var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
    for (var key in icons) {
        var type = icons[key];
        var name = type.name;
        var icon = type.icon;
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = '<br/><img src="' + icon + '"> ' + name;
        legend.appendChild(div);
    }

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER].push(document.getElementById('legend'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(document.getElementById('soy'));
}
```

Esta es una función Ajax que hace la consulta a un controlador, y devuelve un json con los datos de los marcadores que los va pasando a variables mediante un for y así mandarlo al método  addMarker()

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "/usuariofron/devolverpuntos",
    success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var des = (data[i]["punton"]);
            var location = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i]["x"], data[i]["y"]);
            var tipo = (data[i]["id"]);
            addMarker(des, location, tipo, i);
        }
    }
})
```

Este método la da el formato al marcador con que icono debe mostrarse, y le va poniendo en una arreglo con un push

```
 function addMarker(d, l, t, i) {
    if (t == 11) {
        image = "../puntosimg/112.png";
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: l,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
        array.push(marker);
    }
    else if (t== 4){
        image = "../puntosimg/42.png";
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: l,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
        array.push(marker);
    }
    else if (t == 5) {
        image = "../puntosimg/52.png";
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: l,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
        array.push(marker);
    }
    else if (t == 6) {
        image = "../puntosimg/62.png";
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: l,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
        array.push(marker);
    }
    else if (t == 7) {
        image = "../puntosimg/72.png";
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: l,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
        array.push(marker);
    }
    else if (t == 8) {
        image = "../puntosimg/82.png";
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: l,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
        array.push(marker);
    }
    else if (t == 9) {
        image = "../puntosimg/92.png";
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: l,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
        array.push(marker);
    }
    else if (t == 10) {
        image = "../puntosimg/102.png";
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: l,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
        array.push(marker);
    }
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(d);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
}
```

Finalmente este método va insertando los marcadores en el mapa

```
  function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i].setMap(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 preguntas: 1. ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar? 2. ¿En qué momento llamas al `$.ajax`?